# Calling an insertion sort function from a quicksort on Python

Tags: python, quicksort, insertion-sort

I wanted to know if anyone can help me out? I have a simple 2/3 line code to call another function through Python and can't seem to figure it out. The original quicksort2 works, and the insertion sort works, but **the call to the function** is not working (they are in the same directory)- would anyone know what to do? Thanks. I'll post both codes below.

The assignment specifically states: **when n ≤ 16, Quicksort2 will not partition the list but call Insertion Sort instead.** This means I need a simple if-elif statement in my quicksort 2 function, but can't figure out what to do.

```
# insertion sort function for an array 
def insertion_sort(array_values):

    for i in range(1, len(array_values)):

        # condition for previous index greater than current index
        while i > 0 and array_values[i - 1] > array_values[i]:

            # setting our previous index as current index, and current index as previous index
            array_values[i - 1], array_values[i] = array_values[i], array_values[i - 1]

            # decrementing index at i for index pointer
            i -= 1

# testing our insertion sort with a given array of values
array_values = [38,89,27,77,16,86,29,20,1,7]
insertion_sort(array_values)
print(array_values)

# ******************************************

def quicksort2(array, low, high): 

    # THIS PART NEEDS TO CALL MY INSERTION SORT
    #if len(array) <= 16:
        #insertion_sort(array)   
    # THIS PART NEEDS TO CALL MY INSERTION SORT              

    if high > low:
        index = partition(array, low, high)    
        quicksort2(array, low, index - 1)      
        quicksort2(array, index + 1, high)     

def partition(array, low, high):                

    firstitem = array[low]
    j = low

    for i in range(low+1, high+1):            
        if array[i] < firstitem:
            j+=1
            array[j], array[i] = array[i], array[j]
    index = j
    array[low], array[index] = array[index], array[low]     
    return index                               

array = [10, 3, 4, 8, 1, 7, 0, 13]
quicksort2(array, 0, len(array)-1)             
for j in range(len(array)):                    
    print ("%d" %array[j])
```

Comment: You say the functions are in the same directory. Are they in the same _file_? If not, did you import `insertion_sort` into the file with `quicksort`?

Comment: That is it! Thank you. I thought you can call a separate file on Python

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is misleading with "n <= 16". quiksort2 should use insertion sort when a sub-list contains <= 16 elements, when high-low < 16. Insertion sort will need to be modified to take low and high as parameters.